How to Fix Line Numbers in RTL CodeMirror Editor with Custom Layout?
I’m working on a custom CodeMirror editor setup that supports RTL and LTR in the same page. I followed the CodeMirror RTL guide  https://codemirror.net/examples/bidi/  and copied the example to my local server using this command:

wget --mirror --convert-links --adjust-extension --page-requisites --no-parent https://codemirror.net/examples/bidi/

Here’s the HTML code I’m using to understand the RTL:
<!doctype html>
<html lang=en-US>
<meta charset=utf8>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>CodeMirror Right-to-Left Text Example</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../style/site.css">
<style>
  body {
    background-color: #181a1b; 
    color: #ffffff; 
  }

  h1, p {
    color: #ffffff; 
  }

  .CodeMirror-rtl {
    direction: rtl;
    text-align: right;
  }

  .CodeMirror-rtl .CodeMirror-gutters {
    direction: rtl; 
    text-align: right;
    order: 1;
  }

  .CodeMirror-rtl .CodeMirror-sizer {
    margin-right: 30px;
  }

  .CodeMirror-rtl .CodeMirror-scroll {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
  }
</style>
<header>  
</header>
<article>
  <h1 id="example%3A-right-to-left-text" tabindex="-1">Example: Right-to-Left Text</h1>
  <div id="rtl_editor" style="direction: rtl"></div>
  <script src="../../codemirror.js"></script>
  <script src="bidi.js"></script>
</article>
</html>

if i used codemirror.js from a CDN,  I keep getting the following error:

Uncaught ReferenceError: CM is not defined bidi.js:7


Uncaught ReferenceError: CM is not defined bidi.js:80

Additionally, I want to achieve a translation mode layout where the English code is on the left and the Arabic code is on the right. Similar to this demo. https://codemirror.net/5/demo/merge.html

I’ve been trying to fix the issue with the line numbers in the RTL editor for several days, but I haven’t succeeded yet.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CodeMirror/css/codemirror.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CodeMirror/css/dracula.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CodeMirror/css/style.css">
    <title>CodeMirror translate mode</title>   
</head>
<body>
    <div class="editor-container">
        <div class="editor-wrapper">
            <h2>LTR</h2>
            <textarea id="editor-ltr"></textarea>
        </div>
        
        <div class="editor-wrapper" id=rtl_editor style="direction: rtl">
            <h2>RTL</h2>
            <textarea id="editor-rtl" style="direction: rtl;"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div> 
    <script src="CodeMirror/js/codemirror.min.js"></script>    
    <script src="CodeMirror/js/closetag.min.js"></script>
    
</body>
</html>

I used the following commands to download the necessary files:
mkdir -p CodeMirror/css CodeMirror/js
wget -P CodeMirror/css https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/6.65.7/codemirror.min.css
wget -P CodeMirror/css https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/6.65.7/addon/hint/show-hint.min.css
wget -P CodeMirror/css https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/6.65.7/theme/dracula.min.css

wget -P CodeMirror/js https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/6.65.7/codemirror.min.js
wget -P CodeMirror/js https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/6.65.7/mode/python/python.min.js
wget -P CodeMirror/js https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/6.65.7/addon/edit/closetag.min.js
wget -P CodeMirror/js https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/6.65.7/addon/hint/show-hint.min.js
wget -P CodeMirror/js https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/6.65.7/addon/hint/python-hint.min.js

Question:
How can I fix the code to ensure line numbers display correctly in the RTL editor? Any guidance would be appreciated!
